# AWS Nginx ALB Port Configuration

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I used terraform to deploy my k8s cluster, and i used kubectl to deploy nginx on my worker nodes.  Again using kubectl and creating a LoadBalancer targeting the nginx deployment on port 80 worked perfectly fine.  I wanted to test out using an ALB, rather than an ELB.

I deleted the ELB, and then used the EC2 interface to setup a target group.

The target group uses port 80, is on the same vpc, and is targeting the two worker nodes.

[image]

[image]

Next I created an ALB, which is internet facing uses the same security group as the nodes, and again is on the same VPC. Its listening on port 80 and forwarding traffic to my target group.

[image]
[image]

I cant access nginx using the DSN name.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with my port configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not natively support alb's.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller